# My function can not find a class but a case class inside the same Object

Tags: scala

If I change the code below from `class` to `case class` then I works. I don't know why

```
object Test {
  trait T {
    var l = {
      println("l in T initialized")
      "OK"
    }
  }

  class MyClass(x: Int) extends T

  def testTrait() = {
    val t = MyClass(1)

  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not a case class, you need to instantiate it as

```
val t = new MyClass(1)
```

i.e. call its constructor.

The reason why you *don't* need the `new` keyword when it's a case class is that declaring it a case class implicitly defines an `apply` method in your class's companion object; i.e. you get this for free:

```
object MyClass {
  def apply(x: Int): MyClass = {
    new MyClass(x)
  }
}
```

The `apply` method is syntactic sugar in scala which allows for this shorthand notation `MyClass(1)`.

You also get other stuff for free, e.g. an `unapply` method, an `equals` method which implements structural equality and a `toString` method. See more here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html